# How to push state of child component's select tag to parent when parent component's event occurs

Tags: reactjs, arrays, jsx

I've simplified the code for illustrative purposes.

The component below represents a product with multiple options.

```
const Product = () => {
    const [optionsToPost, setOptionsToPost] = useState([]);
    const addToCart = () => {};
    return (
        <>
            <productOptions options={options.color} />
            <productOptions options={options.size} />
            <button onClick={addToCart} />
        </>
    );
};
```

The `productOptions` component displays options as select box.

And It has its own state that stores ID of a option.

```
const productOptions = () => {
    const [option, setOption] = useState();
    return (<select onChange={(e) => {setOption(e.target.value)}}></select>);
};
```

When user selects a option of each select box and presses the button,

I want it to be pushed like `optionsToPost = [10, 14]`

So I created function called `pushToOptions` in product component.

and then I passed it to `productOptions` component, saved the state, and immediately executed it.

But whenever I change a option, It keep pushing.

This doesn't seem like good.

I want to know the simple and elegant way!

Answer (score 0):

Creating the function in the parent component and passing it down to be the click listener is the right idea. If the only problem remaining is that the item gets pushed multiple times, consider only creating an `optionsToPost` item in the parent component when you have the final values needed for an item (perhaps when `addToCart` is called) - before then, have a (singular) state corresponding to each of the `productOptions` that gets changed inside the children.

```
const Product = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState();
  const [size, setSize] = useState();
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const addToCart = () => {
    // perform verification here that both children have had values selected
    if (!color || !size) {
      // display an error to the user if you want
      return;
    }
    setCart([...cart, { color, size }]);
    // or push the numbers corresponding to the state values

    setColor(); // reset the child states
    setSize();
 };
  return (
        <>
            <productOptions value={color} setter={setColor} />
            <productOptions value={size} setter={setSize} />
            <button onClick={addToCart} />
        </>
  );
};
```

If the user wants to push something else to the cart, they'll have to make entirely new selections in both `productOptions` first.

If the number of `productOptions`s is dynamic, that'll mean that the parent state needs to be a bit more complicated - an array of values, one for each `productOptions`, rather than separate states.

```
const Product = () => {
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]); // substitute with the source of the data
  const makeSelectOption = (i) => (e) => {
    // update the value at index i in state
    setSelectedOptions(
      selectedOptions.map((val, j) => j === i ? e.target.value : val)
    );
  };
```

And then pass the state and state setter down to each child like:

```
{
  selectedOptions.map((val, i) => (
    <productOptions value={val} setter={makeSelectOption(i)} />
  ))
}
```

`selectedOptions` will have the array you want (eg, `[10, 14]`). To keep it from being duplicated when the button is pressed, reset the state when the button is pressed (to the empty array or to default values, or whatever you want instead).

Comment: productOptions components are rendered dynamically. Please see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74411559/how-to-handle-object-which-is-created-by-groupby-function-at-once), I am not in a static situation.